# in rtree (python) for a 3d index, how do I create children nodes in the tree and how do I query them?

Tags: python-3.x, r-tree

This probably comes from my poor understanding of the library. 
I know how to query a created index, but I'm trying to learn how to create my own, and I'm a bit lost.

I know how to create an index. The trouble starts when I want to add boxes to it.

1. Are the add and the insert function the same? I see no difference.
2. I have noticed there's 3 arguments to the insert / add function:

   - an id that is not autoincrement
   - the coordinates, where if we want to add a point, we have to make unidimensional box
   - an optional pickle object.

So if I get this right, the way we query the index is by throwing box coordinates at it and the index will return the intersecting objects (boxes).

From the R Tree data structure in wikipedia I have got that the r tree comes from having rectangles inside of rectangles so that each smaller rectangle would be the equivalent of a child node in a binary tree.

The question is: when creating the index, how do we create children nodes? these being the nodes of the tree that fall under the bigger rectangles. Is this remotely useful or should I be thinking this differently?

If it helps I can pose a sample case, but I'd rather get the concept right first.
Thanks in advance, I am having a lot of trouble and I have been at this for far too long, trying queries on an already created tree without fully understanding what's going on.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to your question by yourself? According to the Wikipedia article you mentioned, the boxes are basically created based on the density of points. So, there should kind of be an automatic method to speed up the search on intersections and nearest neighbors.

Comment: I never found an effective way to go with rtree. I have built a tree of queries inside a tree of elements, which works. Unfortunately I have not found the rtree to be speeding up my algorithms at all, and I'm considering dropping it altogether. I am sure there are much more effective ways to do this (even common coordinate searches seem faster).

Comment: I tested this itensly for my use case. I have split a map area of about 400km² into a hex grid and want to match points to hexes. Since the match operation is the expensive operation, I wanted to use rtree to identify a subset of hexes for a point to match. My alternative to rtree is to split the map into 100 sub-sections and apply the match to points and hexes in the subsection. For about 10 points, the rtree is slightly faster. For 100k points, the rtree takes twice the time... so yes, I come to the same conclusion